# Effect of frequent sdcard writes

Tags: android, bufferedwriter, android-sdcard

In my chat app, I am adding the ability to log chats. The logs are saved on the sdcard and one `BufferedWriter` is kept open for every person/channel chat is done with. I'm wondering what effects this might have have on the sdcard and its life.

My `BufferedWriter`'s buffer size is to 1024, I'm also wondering if that is too small or too big.

Comment: Why don't you ask the OS what the filesystem block size is, then set `BufferedWriter` to equal it? This will guarantee the least writes, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash memory cards have an endurance of about [a million write cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompactFlash#Reliability) per area and probably include wear levelling which basically means trying to write to different areas so specific spots dont wear out.

So after about (sizeOfSDCard/sizeOfYourData)*1,000,000 writes, you will have ruined their card.

Practically, this means you probably aren't going to cause any harm.